# Geometry comparisons in SQL

Tags: coordinate-system, geometry, sql, geography-data-type

Newbie to GIS here.

Equality can be defined on a geographic value by seeing if they have a collection of the same points. For example, something like:

```
-- The equality 
-- `LINESTRING(1 1, 2 2) = LINESTRING(2 2, 1 1)`
-- can be expressed as:

SELECT
  ST_EQUALS(
    ST_GEOGFROM('LINESTRING(1 1, 2 2)'), 
    ST_GEOGFROM('LINESTRING(2 2, 1 1)')
  )

-- true
```

Is there any concept of "less than" or "greater than" in a GIS value? For example, maybe a POINT at the equator is "less than" a POINT in Canada? Is there any agreement or meaning of comparisons between two different geographic/geometric values? Or is this something that just does not exist between GEO values (without some sort of additional context ... i.e., it's not a true binary operation)?

Comment: There are a number of comparison operators for geometries, mostly codified in the seminal [Clementini paper](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/A-Small-Set-of-Formal-Topological-Relationships-for-Clementini-Felice/b7f230eeac9b7643a095608bed41faa7a960cb19). The [ST_Equals documentation](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.4/ST_Equals.html) explains why, topologically, 1,1=>2,2 and 2,2=>1,1 are equivalent. "Less than" and "greater than" are not defined with respect to geometry.

Comment: You could compare for example the centroid coordinates

Comment: there are many spatial comparisions - see https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/de9im.html

Comment: Some forms of equality take only the order of the coordinates in to account, others require that they start and stop in the same place.

Comment: This [post](https://www.crunchydata.com/blog/waiting-for-postgis-3-hilbert-geometry-sorting) is worth reading. While being about Postgis only, it shows how geometry ordering (i.e. whose geom is "more" or "less" than another) has evolved through versions.